# Converting JSON Data to a set of Java objects

Tags: java, json

Is there a tool that generates the JSON objects in Java when given JSON data? This tool would either assume one of the "popular" JSON library or would let you specify the JSON library to be used.
For example  with valid JSON data

```
{
    "age":100,
    "name":"mkyong.com",
    "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]
}
```

when using "`org.json.simple.*`" the tool would generate something like this

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "mkyong.com");
obj.put("age", new Integer(100));

JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
list.add("msg 1");
list.add("msg 2");
list.add("msg 3");

obj.put("messages", list);
```

Comment: There are about a hundred different tools for converting to/from JSON.  I don't offhand recall which ones work with Java, but a quick Google would tell you, or you could consult the [JSON website](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Jackson, it's as simple as using an [`ObjectMapper`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html) and creating a POJO to represent your JSON object:

```
public class Person {
  private int age;
  private String name;
  private List<String> messages;

  // getters/setters
}
```

And then:

```
String json = "{\"age\":100,\"name\":\"mkyong.com\",\"messages\":[\"msg 1\",\"msg 2\",\"msg 3\"]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person person = mapper.readValue(json.getBytes(), Person.class);
System.out.println(person.getMessages()); // [msg 1, msg 2, msg 3]
```

To do the reverse, use `writeValue`:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setAge(100);
// ...
mapper.writeValue(..., person);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is a popular framework for converting between JSON and Java POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

[FlexJson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) is also a good library similar to jackson that i have tried.

There are also other options like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/),[FastJson](http://code.alibabatech.com/jira/browse/FASTJSON) and [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) that you can try.

Please share which one did you like and why.

Comment: I went with Jackson - it is fast and easy to use Another interesting Link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library