# Json element in to java set

Tags: java, collections

I want to move the java JSON element(JSON array) into Java set. How do I do that in a simpler manner?

```
JsonElement newdcdc = npsdfs.seget();
```

sample JSON element

```
[
  {
    "expand": "desc",
    "key":"qwe1"
  },
  {
    "expand": "descrip",
    "key":"qwe2"
  },
  {
    "expand": "description",
    "key":"qwe3"
  }
]
```

i need to create some set with all keys so how i do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON Data to a set of Java objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557695/converting-json-data-to-a-set-of-java-objects)

Comment: i need to create java set

Comment: there we can see so many json object in json array

Comment: You have to make them POJO first, and then add Them into a Set.

Comment: do you have any example for that

Comment: It is described in detail in the link above, at the accepted answer. 
you will need an object to map your keys , in this case: expand and key. 
Then with Jackson object mapper, you map the values (desc , qwe1 etc) to your object. Then you can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: can i do it without POJO

Comment: No , unfortunately you cannot.